# No method found in project.filename in Xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a button login on LoginPage.xaml and btnLoginClicked method in code behind in my Xamarin.Forms project. My code is as below-
Xaml :

```
<StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="20" VerticalOptions="Center">

            <ActivityIndicator x:Name="activityIndicator" Color="White" IsRunning="false" IsVisible="false"/>

            <Entry x:Name="entryUsername" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.entryTextColor}" Placeholder="Firstname.Lastname" PlaceholderColor="Gray" IsPassword="false" BackgroundColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.entryBackgroundColor}" />

            <Entry x:Name="entryPassword" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.entryTextColor}" Placeholder="Password" PlaceholderColor="Gray" IsPassword="true" BackgroundColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.entryBackgroundColor}" />

            <Button x:Name="btnLogin" TextColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.btnTextColor}" Text="Login" Clicked="btnLoginClicked"  BackgroundColor="{x:Static color:ColorResources.commonButtonBackgroundColor}"/>

            <Label x:Name="linkForgotPassword"  HorizontalOptions="End" Text="Forgot Password?" TextColor="#0B0FF6"/>    

</StackLayout>
```

Code behind :

```
async public void btnLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
//my stuffs
}
```

When I test my application on iOS simulator its fine but In case of android it gives me error that "No method found btnLoginClicked" in LoginPage. Why is it so?

Comment: Error I mention here appears at the time of debugging app. Not while building app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Clean all project and rebuild all project. And Deploy let me know if solve your problem.

Comment: No. Error is still there.

Comment: Is not found the method, the route of the call method is diferent in Android verify that is you can show me the structure of the folder the route of the arcnive

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

try to reset setting to default in android project properties Like Android Manifest and Android Options.
Make sure you are using shared run-time and fast deployment.